# Setting the default ScrollViewer position/ shown element in a GridView

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm having a list of items bound to a gridview which shows exactly one item on the available screen area. The idea is that I want the user to see exactly one item from the available set while he has the ability to scroll horizontally to the left or the right to show the next/previous items of the list. For this I'm using a GridView along with a SnapPoints enabled scroll viewer. The issue I'm having now is that I couldn't get the GridView to show the default selected item so the user can see for example the 4th or 8th element in the list once he opens the page. I tried by changing the offset of the ScrollViewer of my gridView once the page loads but It does not seem to be working and I get always the first element in the bound list shown. The weird behaviour is that once I call ScrollToHorizontalOffset the ViewChanged event of the scroll viewer gets raised twice, the first one I can see clearly that the offset has been updated to the position of the my default selected item but the second one the offset resets back to the first item.
Bellow it the xaml snippet I'm using for my grid view.

```
            <GridView x:Name="ContentRoot"
            Grid.Row="1"
            IsSwipeEnabled="True"
            IsItemClickEnabled="false"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentWorkout.Exercises}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentExercise}"             
              >
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LargeImagePath}" Width="160" Height="160" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,10" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="24,10" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" />
                        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="24" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap" Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid ItemWidth="380" Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsTapEnabled="False"
                          />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                  VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                                  x:Name="GridScrollViewer" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" 
                                  HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
                                  ViewChanged="ScrollViewer_OnViewChanged">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </GridView.Template>
        </GridView>
```

I'm calling the ScrollToHorizontalOffset from my page loaded event. I also tried on the ScrollViewer loaded event and i get the same behaviour. Same thing for GridView's loaded event. Is there anyway to get the grid view scroll horizontally to the Bound SelectedItem

This is the code I'm using to call the ScrollToHorizontalOffset

```
        int offset = (int)GetItemWidth(mainScrollViewer) *
                    (App.Locator.LearnWorkoutExercicesViewModel.CurrentExerciseIndex + 1);
        mainScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offset);
```

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to find out why ViewChanged was being called twice?

Answer (score 0):

From the analysis of your query, I have noticed that you have set`HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`. in `GridView.Template`
if disabling horizontal scroll bar visibility is not your requirement, 
you can achieve it by

seting `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` in `ScrollViewer` of your `GridView.Template` and 
use `ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(your desire offset)`or `ScrollViewer.ChangeView(your desire offset, 0, 1)` to scroll to the particular offset.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a late answer, but the result you are trying to achieve (1 displayed item, snapping into place while scrolling from one item to the other) seems to be the exact definition of a FlipView. Have you considered using a FlipView instead of a GridView ?